# Word wrap inside content search webpart

Tags: web-part, multiple-lines-of-text

I have a content search web part that I am having an issue with the word wrap. if the site is opened so that the text in the web part is displayed on two lines, the second line is indented to the left of the first line of text.

[image: word wrap example]

I am trying to resolve this using CSS. Any ideas?